# Using Visual Studio and C# capturing only whole words in Regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2013

I've got quite a few regular expressions that I am using to capture info from a String.  One example of a regular expression I am using is to capture a Word like "1ALPHA" :

```
string numUpperCaseStr = "[0-9][A-Z]+";
```

In case's like this when using these regular expressions what I'm curious about is what can I do in the regular expression to ensure I only capture the whole word with other regular expressions.  For example I might have another regular expression like :

```
string allUpperStr = "[A-Z][A-Z]+";
```

if I use that regex I'll capture ALPHA from 1ALPHA and I don't want to.  What can I do to limit these scenarios in regular expressions?

Comment: Not sure if C# would accept this, but you can try something like: `\d[A-Z]+`

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are wanting to know...do you have a code snippet you can post? That way we can more easily see what you wanting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use word boundary:

```
string allUpperStr = "\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b";
```

Comment: What's your thought on using the non greedy +? or *?

Comment: I don't think the greedy operator is useful in this context. It is used to capture only the largest result and ignore the inner acceptable ones. You example is kind of "opposite" problem, you want to avoid to cactch at all something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something along the lines of:

```
(^|\s)([A-Z]{2,})(\s|$)
```

The info you want will be in the second capturing group: [Sample](https://regex101.com/r/uG2bS1/3)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your words are space delimited, you could modify your regular expressions to only return items that both start and end with a space. The actual word can then extracted using a match group

```
(^|\s)([0-9][A-Z]+)(\s|$)
```

By placing parenthesis around the part of the word you want returned, you can then access that segment using match groups